# По мнению экспертов

Tags: пунктуация

По мнению экспертов,"серая часть зарплаты составляет от 30 до 50 процентов реального заработка работника, а, значит, огромные денежные потоки скрыты от налогообложения и бюджеты всех Фондов- пенсионного, медицинского и социального страхования не дополучают средства, идущие впоследствии на выплату пособий, пенсий, на медицинское обслуживание населения.
Нужно ли ставить запятую после "а", нужна ли запятая перед "и бюджеты" (вроде бы есть общее вводное слово значит), надо ли поставить еще одно тире после "страхования". А второй предлог на уместен? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаемый вариант:

По мнению экспертов, серая часть зарплаты составляет от 30 до 50 процентов реального заработка работника, а значит, огромные денежные потоки скрыты от налогообложения и бюджеты всех Фондов - пенсионного, медицинского и социального страхования -  не дополучают средства, идущие впоследствии на выплату пособий, пенсий, медицинское обслуживание населения.

А значит - союз относится к вводному слову.

При обособлении используются два тире (раскрывают содержание слова "всех").

Предлог НА лучше опустить.

Кавычки не нужны, нет дословного цитирования.

Answer (score 0):

*Недополучают* — слитно! Приставка *недо-*.